# Some windows in OS X Lion do not move to foreground when taking focus

Tags: macos, finder, window-manager

I have two windows open (so far I think this has only happened when at least one of the windows is a Finder window, though I'm not sure if that fact is essential to the problem), and I click the one in the background. The previously-focused window changes shade to show that it has lost focus and the now-in-focus window also changes shade to show that it has gained focus, but no matter how many times I click it, it doesn't come to the foreground. I have to try cycling between the windows in order to successfully move-to-background the out-of-focus window and move-to-foreground the in-focus one. Why would this happen? I've never seen such behavior in older versions of OS X and don't think it's a Lion "feature" either.

EDIT: Screenshot attached showing behavior in 10.8
[image: Screenshot of behavior]

Comment: Not going to add this as an answer, as it hardly counts as expert knowledge or hard evidence, but I have been observing the same behavior with Finder windows. I’d very much surmise this is a bug of Lion’s window manager…

Comment: Happens to me, too. I seem to recall it happens more frequently when one of the apps running is in full-screen mode. Have you noticed anything similar?

Comment: Interesting. I never run apps in full-screen mode, so could not comment on that; accordingly, the behavior I have seen only applies to apps in windowed mode.

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate, but I can't find it right now...

Comment: Is it something like http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42827/z-windows-position-lock/42836#42836

Comment: Yes, I believe my problem is the same as @goodfella's (hah). I'll flag it.

Comment: Let's leave both questions. They are worded enough differently and now linked that people should be able to find the answer better now that they are "linked" but have different "search terms worded in the questions".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed this in versions of OS X as far back as Panther. It seems to happen more often with apps that use heavily tweaked windows (like Microsoft Office, Adobe apps, or Java apps, particularly Eclipse).

It's just a bug in the app. File a report with the vendor if you want and maybe they'll be able to fix it.

Comment: Often the problem app is Finder itself...

Comment: @Philip I've never seen Finder do that; it's usually the best-behaved app (as far as windowing goes).

Comment: I'll be curious to see whether I can reproduce the behavior with only Finder and get a screenshot....

Comment: So far I haven't reproduced this behavior in 10.8. I'm tentatively accepting "bug" as the explanation.

Comment: I have reproduced this behavior in 10.8 with only the Finder. Have two folders open, drag a file from one to the other. Other folder comes to foreground, while first folder retains focus. Since it's just Finder, is it still a "bug in the app," i.e. in Finder itself?

Comment: I'd suspect so; the OS X windowing system hasn't changed all that much since OS X was released, so there's probably not very many bugs in it, specially when doing intra-app dragging.